# JQuery interactive gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to create a gallery of four images, positioned vertically, that when clicked move 300px to the right, and then when clicked again move 300px back to the original spot.  This is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingimage ").click(function(){  
        $(this).stop().animate({left:"300px"}, 2000);        
        $(".slidingimage").css("left");                
    });     
});
```

This code moves the images to the right, but I cannot get them to move back to their original location.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function:

```
$(".slidingimage").toggle(function(){
    $(".slidingimage").animate({left:300},600);},
function(){
    $(".slidingimage").animate({left:0},600);
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dy4as/1/)</kbd>

Comment: The Answer gains in quality if you link to the documentation and indent the code nicely. With a Fiddle, then, you win.

Comment: @b__ It was edited with proper documentation, indented nicely and with a Fiddle, I win ;)

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ahIvEYo/1/edit)**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $(".slidingimage").click(function(){  
      $(this).stop().animate({left: this.offsetLeft<150 ? 300 : 0 }, 2000);
    });     

});
```